# trouble with linking from one section to another section using ox-hugo

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am trying to create a link from `content/file.md` to `content/section/_index.md`. I've tried using `CUSTOM_ID`, `ID` and header title in my org file. In the org file, the links work fine. However, after export, `hugo` unable to generate site. It throws an error when trying to process the link in `content/file.md`. The link shows up as `{{<relref "_index" >}}`. This is a problem obviously because it should be `section/_index`.

I hope my problem statement is clear. Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yes: open an issue at the [ox-hugo github site](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo). Likely you will find a higher concentration of ox-hugo enthusiasts there who may be able to help. And if it is a bug, Kaushal will want to fix it.

Comment: Also, you will improve your chances here if you post a minimal but complete org mode file that one could just pick up, export and see the problem for her/himself.

Answer (score 1):

This was a feature request for `ox-hugo` for a while, and it was implemented a couple of weeks back. See [`ox-hugo` Issue #389](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo/issues/389#issuecomment-1071473557) for reference.

---

*For future, feel free to ask any `ox-hugo` related question by creating an issue on the [repo](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo)  for a faster response. If it's a bug I'll attempt to fix it ASAP. If it's a feature request, it might get implemented or not, but after a discussion on that issue thread.*